# How to configure the <run-as> tag for a servlet in a Spring Boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ejb

The old project uses servlet 2.4, Spring 2.5.4, and Struts. Now, we need to upgrade to Spring Boot 2.x. During the upgrade process, we encountered a problem that there is a servlet in the old project, which is defined in the web.xml as follows:

```xml
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>KMUDelegatingServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>crs.gov.ogcio.mars.rm.servlet.RM2KMUDelegatingServlet</servlet-class>
        <run-as>
            <role-name>keyservice_readonly</role-name>
        </run-as>
    </servlet>
```

RM2KMUDelegatingServlet：

```java
public class RM2KMUDelegatingServlet extends EnvPropertiesBase implements Servlet {
    private ServletConfig m_config;
    private Properties m_runtimeProperties;
    private String m_keyOperationsJNDIName;

    public RM2KMUDelegatingServlet() {
    }

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            this.m_config = config;
            this.m_runtimeProperties = this.getRuntimeProperties();
            this.m_keyOperationsJNDIName = this.m_runtimeProperties.getProperty("KEY_OPERATIONS_EJB_REMOTE_JNDI_NAME", "java:global/egis_rm_keyservice/egis_rm_keyservice_ejb/KeyOperations!crs.gov.ogcio.egis.rm.keyservice.appserver.ejb.session.IKeyOperations");
        } catch (Exception var3) {
            this.logError("RM2KMUDelegatingServlet Cannot init RM2KMUDelegatingServlet", var3);
            throw new ServletException("Cannot init RM2KMUDelegatingServlet", var3);
        }
    }

    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return this.m_config;
    }

    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
        boolean alreadyLogged = false;
        InitialContext context = null;
        try {
            String keyName = (String)request.getAttribute(KMUCredentialResolver.KEY_NAME_ATTRIBUTE);
            if (keyName == null) {
                this.logWarn("RM2KMUDelegatingServlet Could not find key name from request");
                alreadyLogged = true;
                throw new Exception("RM2KMUDelegatingServlet Could not find key name from request");
            }
            context = new InitialContext(this.m_runtimeProperties);

            // Get the beans of other ear packages through jndi
            IKeyOperations keyOperations = (IKeyOperations)context.lookup(this.m_keyOperationsJNDIName);
            // This method is marked by @RolesAllowed({"keyservice_readonly", "keyservice_admin", "keyservice_internal"})
            SerializableKeyEntry entry = keyOperations.retrieveEntry(keyName, new Date());

            request.setAttribute(KMUCredentialResolver.KEY_ENTRY_ATTRIBUTE, entry);
        } catch (Exception var16) {
            if (!alreadyLogged) {
                this.logError("RM2KMUDelegatingServlet General exception raised", var16);
            }
            request.setAttribute(KMUCredentialResolver.EXCEPTION_ATTRIBUTE, var16);
        } finally {
            if (context != null) {
                try {
                    context.close();
                } catch (Exception var15) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IKeyOperations：

```java
@Stateless(
    name = "KeyOperations"
)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
@DenyAll
@RunAs("keyservice_internal")
public class KeyOperationsEJB extends EJBBase implements IKeyOperations, IKeyOperationsLocal {

    @RolesAllowed({"keyservice_readonly", "keyservice_admin", "keyservice_internal"})
    public SerializableKeyEntry retrieveEntry(String friendlyAlias, Date forDate) throws KeyStoreException {
        if (!this.initialized) {
            throw new KeyStoreException("KeyService has not been initialized.");
        } else {
            try {
                KeyStoreIndex ksi = this.keystoreIndexDAO.findByFriendlyAlias(friendlyAlias, forDate);
                if (ksi == null) {
                    throw new KeyNotFoundException(friendlyAlias, forDate);
                } else if (!this.verifyKeyStoreIndexEntry(ksi, this.masterCertificate)) {
                    this.logWarn("This KeyStoreInfo record has been tempered. friendlyAlias:" + friendlyAlias + " date:" + forDate);
                    throw new KeyStoreInfoRecordTemperedException(friendlyAlias, forDate);
                } else {
                    KeyStore.Entry entry = this.getEntryFromKeyStore(ksi, this.pwdOpsLocal);
                    SerializableKeyEntry skEntry = new SerializableKeyEntry();
                    if (entry instanceof KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) {
                        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)entry;
                        Certificate cert = privKeyEntry.getCertificate();
                        skEntry.setCertificate((X509Certificate)privKeyEntry.getCertificate());
                        skEntry.setCertificateChain((X509Certificate[])((X509Certificate[])privKeyEntry.getCertificateChain()));
                        skEntry.setPrivateKey(privKeyEntry.getPrivateKey());
                    } else if (entry instanceof KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry) {
                        KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry trustedCertEntry = (KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry)entry;
                        skEntry.setCertificate((X509Certificate)trustedCertEntry.getTrustedCertificate());
                    } else if (entry instanceof KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) {
                        KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry)entry;
                        skEntry.setSecretKey(secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey());
                    }

                    return skEntry;
                }
            } catch (IOException var8) {
                this.logError("IOException", var8);
                throw new KeyStoreException("IOException " + var8.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception var9) {
                this.logError("Exception", var9);
                throw new KeyStoreException(var9.getClass().getName() + var9.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The retrieveEntry method of KeyOperationsEJB is marked with @RolesAllowed, calling keyOperations.retrieveEntry(keyName, new Date()) in RM2KMUDelegatingServlet reports java.security.KeyStoreException of bean: KeyOperations is not allowed, how can I implement  in SpringBoot

Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYEJB0364: Invocation on method: public abstract hk.gov.ogcio.egis.rm.keyservice.common.SerializableKeyEntry hk.gov.ogcio.egis.rm.keyservice.appserver.ejb.session.IKeyOperations.retrieveEntry(java.lang.String,java.util.Date) throws java.security.KeyStoreException of bean: KeyOperations is not allowed

Comment: Implement what. This has nothing to do with SPring Boot but reading on how the Serlvet 3+ API works for java based configuration **or** simply stick to using a web.xml. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I registered RM2KMUDelegatingServlet through the configuration class in SpringBoot, but I don't know how to grant permissions to this servlet.

Comment: describe:
KeyOperationsEJB is located in an ejb project, and its retrieveKey() method is decorated with @RolesAllowed;
RM2KMUDelegatingServlet exists in another SpringBoot project，this servlet gets the KeyOperationsEJB in the ejb project through InitialContext.lookup("java:global/emag/xxxx!xxx.ejb.session.KeyOperationsEJB"), and calls its retrieveKey() method, calling After reporting "KeyOperations is not allowed"

Comment: Ask:
The error should be that RM2KMUDelegatingServlet was not assigned the corresponding role when registering in SpringBoot. In the old project, the assignment of roles was done in web.xml. Can I implement the assignment of roles in SpringBoot

Comment: You haven't shown any configuration, and as stated read how Servlet API 3 works for java configuration which explains the XML alternatives for java. Which also has a run-as equivalent.